# Yii:Is it possible to pass parameter while using window.location.href?

Tags: url, yii

I am trying to call my controller using window.location.href .I don't want to show parameters in my url.
I have button in my form:

```
 <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
 'id'=>'search-form',
 'enableClientValidation'=>true,
 'clientOptions'=>array(
    'validateOnSubmit'=>true,
  ),
)); 
echo CHtml::submitButton('test' ,array(
'onclick'=>'js:act()',  'type' => 'POST', 'id'=>'submitBtn','name' =>'SendButton'));
?>
```

My js code is:

```
function act(){
  var items = [];
  var fields = $(".CCheckBoxColumn").serializeArray(); 
  for(var i=0; i<fields.length; i++){
  items .push(fields[i].value);
  }
  var url='<?php echo $this->createUrl('marketing/composeMail'); ?>';
  window.location.href= url;
}
```

I want to pass my items array in controller method actionComposeMail() without passing it in url.

Comment: use post method instead of get..but show your code so if more easy find a solution..

Answer (score 0):

if you no need to pass a items in url than you need to save in session and other side on method access  item using session

```
$_SESSION['iteam'] = $iteam; // store $iteam array in session indes iteam
```

//retrived in controller using

```
$_SESSION['iteams'];
```

Comment: @ManiRatna if you want to post data wihtout showing in url than you need to form method='post' use this

Comment: i have used method="post" in my form.

Comment: i dont want to show my parameters in url.Is there any way to do so?

Comment: which parameter can you post your full code of form

Comment: I have to pass array named 'items' to my controller.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100032/discussion-between-parth-chavda-and-mani-ratna).